# What is the usage of `podspec` command in Podfile?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

There is a command `podspec` in Podfile ([documentation](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#podspec))

Example from the link:

```
podspec

podspec :name => 'QuickDialog'

podspec :path => '/Documents/PrettyKit/PrettyKit.podspec'
```

What is really mean? a example of project structure that use `podfile` will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old , but I stumble on this question , while learning Cocoapods distribution.

So here is the answer:

As the documentation says. If you define this in your Podfile. All dependencies that you define in your podspec will be installed.

Example:
in your .podspec file you have:

```
spec.dependency "RealmSwift", "~> 0.99.0"
spec.dependency "Starscream", "~> 1.1.3"
```

Basically, this means your library/framework uses this dependencies.

When you are working on your library, you still need to install this dependencies. So you define them in the Podfile of your library:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'YourLibrary' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for YourLibrary
  pod "RealmSwift", "~> 0.99.0"
  pod "Starscream", "~> 1.1.3"

  target 'YourLibraryTest' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

now instead of re-writing all of those dependency that your library needed. You could just use

```
 # Pods for YourLibrary
  podspec
```

this will look through your library/frameworks podspec file. And download the dependencies that were defined.

From the documentation of Cocoapods:

> It is intended to be used by the project of a library.